# Calculate a value with other values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's make it simple:

```
USE Example1

    CREATE TABLE Person
    (PersonID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    FirstName nchar(20) NOT NULL,
    LastName  nchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Salary money NOT NULL
    ) 

        CREATE TABLE Student
        (StudentID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
        FirstName nchar(20) NOT NULL,
        LastName  nchar(20) NOT NULL,
        FatherID int NOT NULL,
        MotherID int NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT fk_Student_FatherID FOREIGN KEY (FatherID)
        REFERENCES Person(PersonID),
        CONSTRAINT fk_Student_MotherID FOREIGN KEY (MotherID)
        REFERENCES Person(PersonID)
        ) 

    CREATE TABLE Registration
    (RegistrationID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    StudentID int NOT NULL,
    Date datetime NOT NULL,
    MonthlyPayment ??????????
    CONSTRAINT fk_Registration_StudentID FOREIGN KEY (StudentID)
    REFERENCES Student(StudentID)
    ) 

    INSERT INTO Person VALUES ('John','Doe','1000')
    INSERT INTO Person VALUES ('Mary','Poppins','800')

    INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('Gary','Doe', 1, 2)

    INSERT INTO Registration VALUES (1, getdate(),???)
```

I have a student that is going to make a registration in a school and have a monthly payment that is going do be `FatherSalary*0.5 + MotherSalary*0.5` but I don't know how to make that happen. I'm new in SQL and maybe this is simple and I should know how to make it, but I don't and I need help.

Comment: What will be the value of Date column in Registration table?

Comment: and - wow - that's expensive :)

Comment: sorry i forgot to put it here, it's getdate()

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you need `MonthlyPayment` column in your table?

You can create table `Registration` without `MonthlyPayment` field and then create a view

```
create view vw_Registration
as
    select
        R.RegistrationID,
        R.StudentID,
        R.Date,
        F.Salary * 0.5 + M.Salary * 0.5 as MonthlyPayment
    from Registration as R
        left outer join Student as S on S.StudentID = R.StudentID
        left outer join Person as F on F.PersonID = S.FatherID
        left outer join Person as M on M.PersonID = S.MotherId
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a41d/1)

Comment: I agree. This should rather be achieved using View. Other options would be to use triggers or UDF.

Comment: Yes I think second option I will think will be trigger, because it's easier to develop and third may be computed column with UDF in declaration. But I like view solution more

Comment: +1 for the solution and, if i could, +1 again for suggesting the view. The formula for MonthlyPayment could change and in a view is easier to manage it:) One thing: Maybe it is safer to use `Coalesce` on `F.Salary` and `M.Salary` :)

Comment: Thank you I'll try that. I haven't learn triggers yet...neither this things but my teacher gave us an assignment where we have to this, well let's see if I can get this to work.

Comment: Yes in general case I'll use `isnull` or `coalesce` for `Salary`, but here's impossible that `Salary` will be null, so it's unnecessary. Based on my expirience, it's better to avoid `isnull` if you will do some queries based on `MonthlyPayment` in `where` clause :)

Comment: Just to add some more information- Try to create Deterministic and Precise view which is a basic requirement for indexed views. Indexed views can boost performance of your query

Answer (score 0):

If the expression "FatherSalary*0.5 + MotherSalary*0.5" will not change, then you can use trigger i suppose.Your trigger will check the inserts to your Registration table. At the time of an insert, it will get the student id, then using this id it will get the necessary data from your student table and your Person table. At that moment, you will have access to the Money column for both father and mother. Calculate the result, and let the trigger to the insert for you.

Answer (score 0):

A view sounds good at first hand, but I can imagine a scenario where you want to calculate a monthly payment based on the data available at a certain point in time so the monthly payment does not change everytime the father or mother has a change in salary...

In that case you can use this:

```
INSERT INTO Registration 
(StudentID, Date, MonthlyPayment)
SELECT S.StudentID, getdate(), ISNULL(F.Salary, 0) * 0.5 + ISNULL(M.Salary, 0) * 0.5
FROM Student as S
left outer join Person as F on F.PersonID = S.FatherID
left outer join Person as M on M.PersonID = S.MotherId
WHERE S.StudentID = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b502a/1/0)